# Java Doughnut Game

Tags: java

I am a beginner to coding and need to write some code to create a simple game that provides a 10x10 matrix board on screen. A  player 'P' moves from bottom left to top right one square at a time by U (Up), D (Down) , L (Left) & R (Right) keyboard strokes, whilst eating doughnuts en-route and avoiding walls with the aim of reaching the Home 'H' position.

The program should randomly place two vertical walls comprising a row of 5 'X's, and one horizontal wall comprising a horizontal row of 5 'X's.
 The two vertical walls should not intersect, but may intersect or abut with the horizontal row. No 'X's should be placed in the leftmost, rightmost, topmost or bottom most row of the board the 'no go zone'.

Five doughnuts symbolised as '@' should be randomly placed. Doughnuts cannot be placed in the 'no go zone', or on any square occupied by a wall. Squares not occupied by a wall, doughnut, player or home are marked with a '.' Once a player lands on a doughnut which he eats, on moving off that square the '@' should be replaced by a '.'.

I am struggling to incorporate the random placement of the walls and doughnuts to comply with the rules outlined above.

```
package doughnut;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Torrin
 */
public class Doughnut {

    static int row = 10;
    static int column = 10;
    static char[][] table = new char[row][column];
    static int num = 5;

    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        setArray();
        displayArray();
        //buildWallsArray();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    static void setArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                table[i][j] = '.';

            }
        }
        table[9][0] = 'P';
        table[0][9] = 'H';
    }

    static void displayArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /*static void buildWallsArray() {
        int counter = 0;
        int X, Y;
        while (counter < num) {
            int i = random.nextInt(8);
            X = i + 1;
            int j = random.nextInt(4);
            Y = j + 3;
            if (table[i][j] == '.') {
                table[i][j] = 'X';
                ++counter;
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
     */
}
```

```
package rand;

import java.util.Random;

    public class Rand {

        private static Random random = new Random();
    //Random placement for vertical walls

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            system.out.print("Running Test");
            vertical();
            horizontal();

        }

        public static void vertical(String[] args) {
            int X, Y;
            int n = random.nextInt(7);
            X = n + 1;
            System.out.print("Vertical X" + "=" + X);
            int m = random.nextInt(3);
            Y = m + 3;
            System.out.println("Vertical Y" + "=" + Y);
        }

    //Random placement of horizontal wall
        public static void horizontal(String[] args) {
            int X, Y;
            int n = random.nextInt(4);
            X = n + 3;
            System.out.print("Horizontal X" + "=" + X);
            int m = random.nextInt(8);
            Y = m + 1;
            System.out.println("Horizontal Y" + "=" + Y);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on where you say you are struggling.  Is your output wrong?  Are you getting an error?  Or is there a concept you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a naive approach:

```
 let x = random position
 while(there is already a wall/donut at position x) {
     x = random position
 }
 place wall/donut at position x
```

This approach will work pretty well, unless your board gets really cluttered -- whereupon the algorithm will have to try so many random positions before finding
a working one, that it will slow the program right down.

Keep using the naive algorithm until it becomes a problem (premature optimisation is evil).

If you need to, design something smarter. I will just describe this one in words. If I have 10 empty spaces in which to place a mark, I can pick a random number between 1 and 10, and mark that number. Now I only have 9 spaces. So I should pick a random number between 1 and 9, and mark that number, **skipping already used squares**.

So, if I've filled slot 5, and my random number is 6, I put the mark in space 7, since that is the 6th empty space.

So:

- count how many empty spaces there are
- let *n* be a random number between 1 and the number of empty spaces
- use the *n*th empty space

I've counted starting from 1 because I've been using plain English. You would probably use 0-indexed space counts.

Comment: Since this is a beginner coder, I strongly discourage other answers from providing non-pseudo code. Best way for OP to learn is to translate pseudocode to Java themselves.